# Customize product page breadcrumbs different from URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

URL format for a product is: **example.com/product/sample-product**

Breadcrumb format for that same product on its page is: **Home > Product > Sample Product**

URL format is fine. But please tell how to change the breadcrumb format to the one mentioned below with the same URL format

**Home > Sample Parent Category > Sample Child Category > Sample Product**

I want to change the breadcrumbs format only on product pages and nowhere else on the site. Hierarchy of categories can be more than 2. Also please suggest how to do this using child theme.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce by default should do that. (My fresh install of version 4.9.1 does it.) But maybe some plugin or theme hooks into the breadcrumb generation and prevents this?

You might want to have a look inside `/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-breadcrumb.php`, specifically the `generate`, `add_crumbs_single` and `term_ancestors` methods.